# SQL statement confusion

Tags: sql

I have a table that will have data like this

```
PRODUCTID | GENREID
1         | 5
1         | 6
1         | 8
2         | 5
2         | 10
3         | 6
```

And I'm trying to write a statement to where if I provide the numbers 5, 6 and 8, it will only return to me ProductID '1'.  My initial thought was to write something like this, but I'm starting to confuse myself as I'm not a SQL ninja :

```
select 
    p1.productid 
from 
    dbo.ProductGenre p1 
inner join
    dbo.ProductGenre p2 on p2.GenreID = p1.GenreID 
where 
    p1.GenreID = 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT productid
FROM   dbo.productgenre
WHERE  genreid IN ( 5, 6, 8 )
GROUP  BY productid
HAVING Count(DISTINCT genreid) = 3
```

Comment: I tried applying your SQL format to match my data but it's not returning anything

Comment: The statement above is missing an "s". sometimes in our hurry we copy-paste and run it. Just wondering if you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: @abhi I noticed that when I copy and pasted it and added the 's' to select, but it wasn't returning data, thanks though

Comment: That query works for me and returns 1. My guess is that you're pasting some test data in your question, but trying to run the query with real data.

Comment: @abhi Would not having an exact match of data make any difference?  I substituted the test data that I provided in the question with real data that I know is there. (did a select * from productgenre and added in some of the values to try to reproduce a productID)  The only difference would be  in the data I provided "5,6,8" to productID 1, there might be also "10,15,18" also mapped to productID 1.  Would this be an issue?

Comment: Damnit...I feel really stupid.  My new query window was pointed at master instead of the database I was working with so I wasn't getting proper results...this works perfectly. Thanks and sorry!